# Error when I try to add an image web service prestashop

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to add an image to a product using web services, but everytime I try, I get an error. In almost all the pages I have searched this is the code they gave me:

```
    $key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; //WebService Key
    $url = 'https://192.168.1.124/prestashop/api/images/products/2';
    $imagen = 'C:\\camisa.png';


    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true); // Un-commet to edit an image

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$key.':');
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('image' => '@'.$imagen.';type=image/png'));
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo "<h3>Imagen añadida</h3>";
```

But it always gives me the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZDsO.png).

Error Translation:

The page 192.168.1.124 doesn't work.

The page 192.168.1.124 can't process this request right now.

Any help will be appreciated.
Greetings!

Comment: Please find the english translation for the error and include it into the the question as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I named the file 'Añadir Imagen' and it seems that localhost doesn't recognize the 'ñ' character.

Hope that it helps someone with the same problem.

Greetings!